# Labeling Plots?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I haven't been able to find anything on this after searching for a while, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I need to replicate the following image:

[image]

Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

%%for graphs
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%%end graph code

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=bottom,%need to change to bottom to put 0 in 
            axis y line=middle,
            x label style={at={(axis cs: 2.6, -0.12)},anchor=south},%rotate = degrees number can be used to rotate the label
            y label style={at={(axis cs:0, 2.5)},anchor=south},
            xtick={0, 1, 2}, %or {listofvalues, , },
            ytick={0, 1, 2},
            yticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
            xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=2.5,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=2.5,
            ylabel=$y$, 
            xlabel=$x$,
            area style,
            ]
        %thick lines
        \draw[draw = black, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 2);
        \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = upper, domain=0:2] {2-x};
        \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = lower, domain=0:2] {0};  
        %shading    
        \addplot[gray!40] fill between[of = upper and lower];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

It doesn't matter to me where the axis labels are - the main problem is trying to get the x + y = 2 on the line.

How can I get the x + y = 2 on the line?

Comment: Follow up question: [Circular ends of lines and positioning of nodes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184747/circular-ends-of-lines-and-positioning-of-nodes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to place a node:

```
\node [rotate=-45, above] at (axis cs: 1,1) {$x + y = 2$};
```

which requires the use of the `axis cs` coordinate system and a `rotate=`.

Alternatively, you can place the node as part of the `\addplot` using the `sloped` option:

```
    \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = upper, domain=0:2] {2-x} 
          node [midway, sloped, above, red] {$x + y = 2$};
```

[image]

### Notes:

- Please see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided/42115#42115)

---

### Code: `Manual Node`:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%for graphs
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%%end graph code

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=bottom,%need to change to bottom to put 0 in 
            axis y line=middle,
            x label style={at={(axis cs: 2.6, -0.12)},anchor=south},%rotate = degrees number can be used to rotate the label
            y label style={at={(axis cs:0, 2.5)},anchor=south},
            xtick={0, 1, 2}, %or {listofvalues, , },
            ytick={0, 1, 2},
            yticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
            xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=2.5,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=2.5,
            ylabel=$y$, 
            xlabel=$x$,
            area style,
            ]
        %thick lines
        \draw[draw = black, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 2);
        \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = upper, domain=0:2] {2-x};
        \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = lower, domain=0:2] {0};  
        %shading    
        \addplot[gray!40] fill between[of = upper and lower];
        \node [rotate=-45, above] at (axis cs: 1,1) {$x + y = 2$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

---

## Code: `Node as part of \addplot`:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%for graphs
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%%end graph code

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=bottom,%need to change to bottom to put 0 in 
            axis y line=middle,
            x label style={at={(axis cs: 2.6, -0.12)},anchor=south},%rotate = degrees number can be used to rotate the label
            y label style={at={(axis cs:0, 2.5)},anchor=south},
            xtick={0, 1, 2}, %or {listofvalues, , },
            ytick={0, 1, 2},
            yticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
            xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=2.5,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=2.5,
            ylabel=$y$, 
            xlabel=$x$,
            area style,
            ]
        %thick lines
        \draw[draw = black, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 2);
        \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = upper, domain=0:2] {2-x} node [midway, sloped, above, red] {$x + y = 2$};
        \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = lower, domain=0:2] {0};  
        %shading    
        \addplot[gray!40] fill between[of = upper and lower];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```