# Circular ends of lines and positioning of nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to replicate the following image:

[image]

My work so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%for graphs
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%%end graph code

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,%need to change to bottom to put 0 in 
        axis y line=middle,
        x label style={at={(axis cs: 2.6, -0.12)},anchor=south},%rotate = degrees number can be used to rotate the label
        y label style={at={(axis cs:0, 2.5)},anchor=south},
        xtick={0, 1, 2}, %or {listofvalues, , },
        ytick={0, 1, 2},
        yticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
        xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2.5,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=2.5,
        ylabel=$y$, 
        xlabel=$x$,
        area style,
        ]
    %thick lines
    \draw[draw = black, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 2);
    \draw[draw = black, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0.5, 0) -- (axis cs: 0.5, 1.5) node [above, right] {$y = 2 - x$};
    %y=0 label
    \node [below] at (axis cs: 0.5,0) {$y=0$};
    %line with label
    \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = upper, domain=0:2] {2-x} node [midway, sloped, above, black] {$x + y = 2$};
    %node for labeling line
    \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = lower, domain=0:2] {0};  
    %shading    
    \addplot[gray!40] fill between[of = upper and lower];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The main issues are that the node labels aren't appearing and and positioned correctly, and I'm not sure how to get the circular ends of lines.

Thanks for any help - sorry if these questions have already been answered elsewhere.

Comment: This is a follow up to: [Labeling Plots?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184733/labeling-plots).

Comment: Just for the circle ends, if you add `usetikzlibrary{arrows}` in your preamble you could then use `\draw[-*] (0,0) -- (1,1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply `clip=false` and place `circle` nodes. You also had `above, right` which effectively is `right` -- I think you meant `above right`.

[image]

Also, if you want to use a different color for the vertical line (as shown above), it is better to draw outside of the `axis` environment so that the filled circle is displayed correctly:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%for graphs
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%%end graph code

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,%need to change to bottom to put 0 in 
        axis y line=middle,
        x label style={at={(axis cs: 2.6, -0.12)},anchor=south},%rotate = degrees number can be used to rotate the label
        y label style={at={(axis cs:0, 2.5)},anchor=south},
        xtick={0, 1, 2}, %or {listofvalues, , },
        ytick={0, 1, 2},
        yticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
        xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2.5,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=2.5,
        ylabel=$y$, 
        xlabel=$x$,
        area style,
        clip=false,
        ]
    %y=0 label
    \node [below] at (axis cs: 0.5,0) {$y=0$};
    %line with label
    \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = upper, domain=0:2] {2-x} 
        node [midway, sloped, above, black] {$x + y = 2$};
    %node for labeling line
    \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = lower, domain=0:2] {0};  
    %shading    
    \addplot[gray!40] fill between[of = upper and lower];
    %thick lines
    \draw[draw = black, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 2);
    \draw[draw = red, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0.5, 0) -- (axis cs: 0.5, 1.5) 
        node [draw=red, circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt, pos=0]  {}
        node [draw=red, circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt, pos=1]  {}
        node [above right] {$y = 2 - x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Draw outside of `axis` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%for graphs
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%%end graph code

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,%need to change to bottom to put 0 in 
        axis y line=middle,
        x label style={at={(axis cs: 2.6, -0.12)},anchor=south},%rotate = degrees number can be used to rotate the label
        y label style={at={(axis cs:0, 2.5)},anchor=south},
        xtick={0, 1, 2}, %or {listofvalues, , },
        ytick={0, 1, 2},
        yticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
        xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2.5,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=2.5,
        ylabel=$y$, 
        xlabel=$x$,
        area style,
        clip=false,
        ]
    %y=0 label
    \node [below] at (axis cs: 0.5,0) {$y=0$};
    %line with label
    \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = upper, domain=0:2] {2-x} 
        node [midway, sloped, above, black] {$x + y = 2$};
    %node for labeling line
    \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = lower, domain=0:2] {0};  
    %shading    
    \addplot[gray!40] fill between[of = upper and lower];
    %thick lines
    \draw[draw = black, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 2);

    \coordinate (TOP) at (axis cs: 0.5, 1.5);
    \coordinate (BOT) at (axis cs: 0.5, 0);
\end{axis}
    \draw[draw = red, ultra thick] (BOT) -- (TOP) 
        node [draw=red, circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt, pos=0]  {}
        node [draw=red, circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt, pos=1]  {}
        node [above right] {$y = 2 - x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add two extra nodes for the circles and define the text relative to them. Note that to draw outside the axes you have to turn on `clip=false`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%for graphs
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%%end graph code

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,%need to change to bottom to put 0 in 
        axis y line=middle,
        x label style={at={(axis cs: 2.6, -0.12)},anchor=south},%rotate = degrees number can be used to rotate the label
        y label style={at={(axis cs:0, 2.5)},anchor=south},
        xtick={0, 1, 2}, %or {listofvalues, , },
        ytick={0, 1, 2},
        yticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
        xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2.5,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=2.5,
        ylabel=$y$, 
        xlabel=$x$,
        area style,
        clip=false,%<-- This option needs to be added
        ]
    %thick lines
    \draw[draw = black, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 2);
    \node[circle,fill] at (axis cs:0.5,1.5) (a) {};%<---- Here is for drawing the circle
    \draw[draw = black, ultra thick] (axis cs: 0.5, 0) -- (axis cs: 0.5, 1.5)
        node[anchor=south west] at (a.north east) {$y = 2 - x$};
    %y=0 label
    \node[circle,fill] at (axis cs:0.5,0) (b) {};%<---- Here is for drawing the circle
    \node[anchor=north] at (b.south) {$y=0$};
    %line with label
    \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = upper, domain=0:2] {2-x} node [midway, sloped, above, black] {$x + y = 2$};
    %node for labeling line
    \addplot+[draw = black, ultra thick, name path = lower, domain=0:2] {0};  
    %shading    
    \addplot[gray!40] fill between[of = upper and lower];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]